# How to intialize a PDB.DSSP object correctly

Tags: python, ubuntu, biopython

I am trying to get DSSP of a PDB file but python is throwing File not found.

I downloaded dssp from window's Ubuntu. 
Calling which dssp in the ubuntu terminal gives'/usr/bin/dssp'
Calling dssp with the pdb file gives out the correct output.
It could be possible the path is wrong in my ide.

```
 p = PDB.PDBParser()      
 structure = p.get_structure(PDB_file[:-4].upper(), dir + "/" + PDB_file)
 model = structure[0]
 dssp=DSSP(model,PDB_file)
```

The three previous lines work fine. i've trying adding dir (the directory) to the constructor to no avail